# Integral of simple functions in standard and non-standard representation

Tags: measure-theory

**Some definitions**

Let $(X,\mathbb X,\mu)$ be a measure space. 
A real-valued function is *simple* if it has only a finite number of values. A simple $\mathbb X$-measurable function $\varphi$ can be represented in the form
  $$\varphi=\sum_{j=1}^n a_n\chi_{E_j}$$
where $a_j\in\mathbb R$ and $\chi_{E_j}$ is the characteristic function of a set $E_j\in\mathbb X$. If we add the restriction that the $a_j$ be distinct and the $E_j$ form a partition of X, then the representation is unique and is called the *standard representation* of $\varphi$.

If $\varphi$ is a simple function in $M^+(X,\mathbb X)$ with the standard representation above, we define the integral of $\varphi$ with respect to $\mu$ to be the extended real number
  $$\int\varphi\,d\mu=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\mu(E_j)$$

**My question**

If the simple function $\varphi\in M^+(X,\mathbb X)$ has the (not necessarily standard) representation
  $$\varphi=\sum_{k=1}^m b_k\chi_{F_k}$$
where $b_k\in\mathbb R$ and $F_k\in\mathbb X$, it can be shown that
  $$\int\varphi\,d\mu = \sum_{k=1}^m b_k\,\mu(F_k).$$
My problem is that I cannot find a *clean* yet rigorous step-by-step proof of that result.

My idea is to rewrite the function $\varphi$ as $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\chi_{\phi^{-1}(a_k)}$ where $a_k$ is the sum of some $b_k$ terms and $\phi^{-1}(a_k)$ is the union of intersections of some $F_k$ terms. After some manipulations I note that I can put back together all the "pieces" and find $\sum_{k=1}^m b_k\,\mu(F_k)$. Unfortunately, that very last passage is left to the reader. Is there a way to make all the process explicit and yet clean and easy to follow?

Comment: By non-standard you mean the non-standard analysis, like $m$ being an infinite number?

Comment: @Ilya. I believe by standard he means that the sets $F_{k}$ make a partition of $X$.

Comment: Yes, I meant what Thomas said.

Comment: does $\varphi\in \Bbb M^+$ mean that it is non-negative?

Comment: Yes, it means that it is a non-negative measurable function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose $m$ is finite. Using the linearity of the integral, we have
$$
  \int \left(\sum_{k=1}^m b_k1_{F_k}(x)\right)\mu(\mathrm dx) = \sum_{k=1}^m
b_k\int1_{F_k}(x)\mu(\mathrm dx) = \sum_{k=1}^mb_k\mu(F_k)
$$
regardless of the shape of the collection $F_k$.

If you don't want to use linearity, note that given some finite collection $\{F_k\}_{k=1}^m$ of measurable sets there is a unique coarsest partition $\mathscr G = \{G_i\}_{i=1}^n$ such that $F_k$ are unions of some elements in $\mathscr G$. Let $g:\{1,\dots,n\}\to2^{\{1,\dots,m\}}$ be the index function uniquely defined by
$$
  k\in g(i)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad G_i\subset F_k
$$
for any $k\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ and any $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. Furthermore, note that for any $k\in \{1,\dots,m\}$ the inverse of $g$ satisfies
$$
  \{i:k\in g(i)\} = \{i:G_i\subset F_k\}
$$
is partition of $F_k$ in $\mathscr G$. In particular, $\mu(F_k) = \sum_{i:k\in g(i)}\mu(G_i).$ Then we have:
$$
  \varphi(x) = \sum_{k=1}^m b_k1_{F_k}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{k\in g(i)}b_k\right)1_{G_i}(x)
$$
where the first equality is the definition of $\varphi$ and the latter function is standard simple one. Thus
$$
  \int\varphi\;\mathrm d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{k\in g(i)}b_k\right)\mu(G_i) = \sum_{k=1}^n b_k\left(\sum_{i:k\in g(i)}\mu(G_i)\right) = \sum_{k=1}^n b_k\mu(F_k)
$$
where we passed from the summation over $G_i$ to the summation over $b_k$.

Comment: We do not need to use the dominated convergence theorem, nor the linearity of the integral. The simple functions I am talking about take just a finite number of real values (i.e. their image is finite).

Comment: @Kiuhnm: if their image is finite, doesn't the first part of my reply answers your question?

Comment: I would like to prove it without using the linearity of the integral, i.e. just by using the definition of the integral of simple functions (see the latest revision of my question). To say it another way, this question is more about sum and set manipulations than about measure theory.

Comment: @Kiuhnm: I guess, now it answers your question better.

Comment: Thank you; that's exactly what I was looking for.
 
I tried to edit your post but I couldn't because I wanted to change just two characters. The limits of the last and the third from last summation might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat more constructive proof.

$$
f = \sum_{k = 1}^{m} b_{k}\chi_{B_{k}} \implies \int f d\mu = \sum_{k = 1}^{m} b_{k}\mu({B_{k}})
$$

Let $ \mathcal{I} = \{1,...,m\} $, $ I \doteq \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{I})\backslash\{\emptyset\} $.

Let $ \alpha \in I $, define:
$$
C_{\alpha} = 
\left(
\bigcap_{i \in \alpha} B_{i}
\right)
\cap 
\left( 
\bigcap_{j \in \mathcal{I}\backslash \alpha} X\backslash B_{j} 
\right) 
$$

in fact $ \alpha \neq \beta \implies C_{\alpha} \cap C_{\beta} = \emptyset $.

Let $ \sim $ equivalence relation over $ I $ defined as $ \alpha \sim \beta \iff \sum_{k \in \alpha} b_{k} = \sum_{k \in \beta}b_{k} $. Seja $ a_{\bar{\alpha}} \doteq \sum_{k \in \alpha}b_{k} $ well defined in $ I/\sim $, let $ A_{\bar{\alpha}} \doteq \sqcup_{\gamma \in \bar{\alpha}}C_{\gamma} $.

Statement: the can. rep. of $ f $ is:

$$
f = \sum_{\bar{\alpha} \in I/\sim}a_{\bar{\alpha}}\chi_{A_{\bar{\alpha}}}
$$

hence:

$$
\int f d\mu = \sum_{\bar{\alpha} \in I/\sim}a_{\bar{\alpha}}\mu(A_{\bar{\alpha}})
$$

but $ a_{\bar{\alpha}}\mu(A_{\bar{\alpha}}) = a_{\bar{\alpha}}\sum_{\gamma \in \bar{\alpha}} \mu(C_{\gamma})  = \sum_{\gamma \in \bar{\alpha}}a_{\bar{\alpha}}\mu(C_{\gamma}) = \sum_{\gamma \in \bar{\alpha}}a_{\bar{\gamma}}\mu(C_{\gamma}) = \sum_{\gamma \in \bar{\alpha}}(\sum_{i \in \gamma}b_{i})\mu(C_\gamma)$, thus:

$$
\int f d\mu = \sum_{\bar{\alpha} \in I/\sim}\sum_{\gamma \in \bar{\alpha}}\sum_{i \in \gamma}b_{i}\mu(C_\gamma)
$$

on the other hand:

$$
B_{k} = \bigsqcup_{\gamma \in I(k \in \gamma)}C_{\gamma} \implies \mu(B_{k}) = \sum_{\gamma \in I(k \in \gamma)} \mu(C_{\gamma})
$$

$$
 \sum_{i = 1}^{m}b_{i}m(B_{i}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{m}\sum_{\gamma \in I(i \in \gamma)} b_{i} \mu(C_{\gamma}) = \sum\{b_{i}\mu(C_{\gamma}):i \in \{1,...,m\} \land \gamma \in I \land i \in \gamma \} = 
$$

$$
 = \sum_{\gamma \in I} (\sum_{i \in \gamma} b_{i}) C_{\gamma} = \sum_{\bar{\alpha} \in I/\sim}\sum_{\gamma \in \bar{\alpha}}\sum_{i \in \gamma} b_{i}C_{\gamma} = \int f d_{\mu \quad \square}
$$